# How do I organize a JSON by Values when my keys are random?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

So, I'm trapped on one thing here, I receive a JSON by API and need to organize that from the major value to the minor. That is my problem... See, all my keys: values changes every time, they're not static.

Follow my code below:

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Serial Number</h3>
                </div>

                    <div class="form-row">

                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label></label>
                            <form method="post" action="#">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uwipkey">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                      <button type="button" id="sendPredictRequest"class="btn btn-info btn-flat" >Executar</button>
                                    </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>

                <div class="box-footer">
                    <div >
                       
                    </div>
                    <!-- Fim do Formulario com upload Files -->
                </div>


                <!-- /.box -->

            </div>
            <!--/.col (right) -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h2 class="box-title">Result</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div id="charts"></div>
                    <div id="charts2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



<!--_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_ FUNCAO SUBMIT FORM _*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_-->
<script>


    $('#sendPredictRequest').click(function(){
        uwip=$('#uwipkey').val()
        $.getJSON('http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/predict/' + uwip, function(data){
            console.log('success');

            var mappedHash = Object.keys( data ).sort(function( a, b ) {
                return data[ a ].rank - data[ b ].rank;
            }).map(function( sortedKey ) {
                return data[ sortedKey ];
            });

           /*
            Tried this as well, but I got the same output
            var arrData = [data];
            arrData.sort();
           */

            $('#charts').html(JSON.stringify(data));

        }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log( "error" );
            $('#result').html("error" + error);
          })
        
          $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "webservices/ws_ai/repair_recomendation.php",
              data:{
                  uwip: uwip
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                // Para o usuário esperar o final do carregamento da página
                $("#charts2").html("<center><img src='pages/qualityMetrics/img/gears.gif' style='width: 100px; height: 100px;'/> Enviando...</center>");
                },
                success: function (result) {
                //console.log(result);
                $("#charts2").html(result);
                }
                

              
          })
    });
 
    
</script>
```

My output from this is

```
{"BOOT KILL + MEDIA BUILD":0.08,"MOTHERBOARD":0.92,"WLAN":0.0}
```

Basically I receive a result from a AI recommending what action I need to take to repair a PC, but I need to organize that gives me the major value first, then the second major, then the minor result(don't forget that the keys and values can change all the time). Do you have any idea how to proceed with that?

Already tried to convert it into an array and use the sort() method, didn't work, tried as my code up here a map() also didn't work. Please Help me!

Comment: @JaromandaX , Don't know why that did not work, but I got the same out put that is in my question, think maybe it is sorting by keys, alphabetically, see BOOT KILL + MEDIABUILD comes first than MOTHERBOARD

Comment: so, you sorted on keys rather than values

Comment: Yes, but I did not know how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your success function you can manipulate result. like:

```
success: function (result) {
$("#charts2").html('');
$.each(sortReponse(result), function (key, value) {
 
                    $("#charts2").append('<p><span>' + value.key + '</span><span>' + value.value + '</span></p>');
                });
}
```

you may need a sorting function to add

```
function sortReponse(data)
{
    var sorted = [];
    $(data).each(function(k, v) {
        for(var key in v) {
            sorted.push({key: key, value: v[key]})
        }
    });

    return sorted.sort(function(a, b){
        if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
        if (a.value > b.value) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Update: Here in your case ( if you mean this api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON ) try inside .done function.

Comment: That seem pretty clear to me, my only question is that the first code that you answered me I need to put that on _getJson_ result, the success function I bring just a table, my API Result comes from getJson function, so where do I put this code?

Comment: if you mean this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ try inside .done function.

Comment: Wow @Rosh_LK, thanks a lot! Worked really well here! I'm so grateful!

Comment: @LeonardoBombassei glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array#sort()

```
    var data = [ // YOUR DATA  ];
    
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    });

`document.write('<tag>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 3) + '</tag>')`;
```

Comment: Sorry, saw now you tried using Array sort